# Sorting an array in spring-data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection like :

```
{"x":{"y":[
{"date":ISODate("2014-07-24T21:00:00.000Z"),"k":5 },
{"date":ISODate("2014-07-22T21:00:00.000Z"),"k":6 } ] }}
```

I want to sort y array according to "date" parameter.So i made the code like this :

```
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "y.date"));
```

I want to output like this:

```
{"x":{"y":[
    {"date":ISODate("2014-07-22T21:00:00.000Z"),"k":5 },
    {"date":ISODate("2014-07-24T21:00:00.000Z"),"k":6 } ] }}
```

How can i make the output like this ? is the code that i made ,it is ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using aggregation, your query should look like this, since you want to sort elements of 'y' based on 'date' in ascending order.

> db.test.aggregate([   {$unwind: "$y"},
>   {$sort: {"y.date":1}},
>   {$group: {_id:"$_id", y: {$push:"$y"}}} ]);

Comment: thanx @vmr.But "unwind" already split the documents and every document has one y...sorting has no mean in like this situation.

Comment: The order will be maintained during grouping per _id, so it should reach your target.